# Set when the Chartboost Interstitial Ad should show up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chartboost

Somehow I need to set that my Chartboost Interstitial Ad would show up when I want, because It just poping up randomly (even in the Game itslef, when the player is playing). I'm trying to do this in UNITY3D in C#.

There's the code in my CBScript.cs, which basicaly contains all the needed information to load my Ads from Chartboost. I added this script to my empty GameObject in my Hierarchy view.

CBScript.cs:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;
    using Chartboost;


    public class CBScript : MonoBehaviour {

        #if UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE

        public void Update() {
            #if UNITY_ANDROID
            // Handle the Android back button (only if impressions are set to not use activities)
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)) {
                // Check if Chartboost wants to respond to it
                if (CBBinding.onBackPressed()) {
                    // If so, return and ignore it
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, handle it ourselves -- let's close the app
                    Application.Quit();
                }
            }
            #endif
        }

        void OnEnable() {
            // Initialize the Chartboost plugin
            #if UNITY_ANDROID
            // Replace these with your own Android app ID and signature from the Chartboost web portal
            CBBinding.init("ID", "Signature");
            #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            // Replace these with your own iOS app ID and signature from the Chartboost web porta

l
        CBBinding.init("ID", "Signature");
        #endif
    }

    void OnApplicationPause(bool paused) {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        // Manage Chartboost plugin lifecycle
        CBBinding.pause(paused);
        #endif
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        // Shut down the Chartboost plugin
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        CBBinding.destroy();
        #endif
    }
    // UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE
    #endif
}
```

And now I'm going to show you guys, how I implemented this code to one of my Game functions. I really want that my Chartboost Interstitial Ad would show up after when the player loses and Game over screen shows up. So this is the snippet from my GUI script, ShowEnd function:

```
//Shows the end menu after a crash
    public void ShowEnd()
    {
        //Save the mission and activate the finish menu
        MissionManager.Instance.Save();
        EnableDisable(finishMenu, true);

        //Get the current coin and distance data
        int currentDist = (int)LevelGenerator.Instance.distance;
        int currentCoins = LevelManager.Instance.Coins();

        //Apply the data to the finish menu
        finishTexts[0].text = currentDist + "M";
        finishTexts[1].text = currentCoins.ToString();

        //If the current distance is greater than the best distance
        if (currentDist > SaveManager.GetBestDistance())
            //Set the current distance as the best distance
            SaveManager.SetBestDistance(currentDist);

        //Add the collected coins to the account
        SaveManager.SetCoins(SaveManager.GetCoins() + currentCoins);

        //Show the finish menu
        StartCoroutine(FadeScreen(0.4f, 0.7f));
        StartCoroutine(MoveMenu(finishMenu.transform, 0, -14.8f, 0.55f, false));

        OnGUI ();

    }
```

And this is `OnGUI();` function, which catches and actually showing the Interstitial Ad:

```
void OnGUI(){
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        // Disable user input for GUI when impressions are visible
        // This is only necessary on Android if we have disabled impression activities
        //   by having called CBBinding.init(ID, SIG, false), as that allows touch
        //   events to leak through Chartboost impressions
        GUI.enabled = !CBBinding.isImpressionVisible();
        #endif

        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.Scale(new Vector3(2, 2, 2));
        CBBinding.cacheInterstitial("Default");
        CBBinding.showInterstitial("Default");
    }
```

Like I said, CB Interstitial Ads showing up randomly. I want that my Ad only show up immediately after Game Over screen. I know I'm doing everything wrong right now, but I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you and appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you should cache the interstitials at the startup of your game, probably in the OnEnable function of one of your GameObjects. I would suggest you do that in the OnEnable of the gameobject to which you are attaching the GUI.

```
void OnEnable() {
    CBBinding.cacheInterstitial("Default");
}
```

And inside the OnGUI() function you should first check for an interstitial and then call the showInterstitial()

```
void OnGUI(){
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        // Disable user input for GUI when impressions are visible
        // This is only necessary on Android if we have disabled impression activities
        //   by having called CBBinding.init(ID, SIG, false), as that allows touch
        //   events to leak through Chartboost impressions
        GUI.enabled = !CBBinding.isImpressionVisible();
        #endif

        GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.Scale(new Vector3(2, 2, 2));
        if (CBBinding.hasInterstitial("Default"))
            CBBinding.showInterstitial("Default");
    }
```